# How can I get a python counter to work in a function with multiple if statements?

Tags: python, counter

I've got a big function that simulates a systems of reactions over time. I've added in a `leap_couner` to count the number of steps through time.

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, delta_t, tao, epsi):
    t = simulation_timer()
    t.start()
    while tao < tmax:
        propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)    
        a0 = (sum(propensity))  
        if a0 == 0.0:  
            print("Propensity sum is zero end execution")   
            break   
        if popul_num.any() < 0:       
            print("Molecules numbers below zero end execution")
            break
        lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)    
        rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam) 
        if tao + delta_t > tmax:
            break    
        tao += delta_t 
        leap_counter = 0
        if delta_t >= 1 / a0:
            for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):  
                state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
                popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda   
                leap_counter += 1    # Not working!
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
            tao_all.append(tao) 
            leap_counter += 1  
        else:   # else execute the ssa because it's faster
            next_t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
            rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
            num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
            if tao + next_t > tmax:      
                tao = tmax
                break
            j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
            tao = tao + next_t
            popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))  
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
            tao_all.append(tao)    
    print("Molecule numbers:\n", popul_num)
    print("Time of final simulation:\n", tao)
    print("leap counter:\n", leap_counter)
    t.stop()
    return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao), popul_num
```

Thats the full function and heres the specific bit with the counter:

```
if tao + delta_t > tmax:
    break    
tao += delta_t 
leap_counter = 0
if delta_t >= 1 / a0:
    for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):  
        state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
        popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda   
        leap_counter += 1    # Not working!
    popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
    tao_all.append(tao)
```

`tao` is the current time, `delta_t` is the value to increase by and `tmax` is the maximum simulation time. If `tao + delta_t` is less than `tmax` then the current time is incremented by `delta_t`.

I then use `delta_t` to determine which leap method I use. If I use the first leap method `if delta_t >= 1/a0` then I want to count each time increment (by `delta_t`) and return the number of increments `leap_counter`

Only I'm having trouble with the counter at the moment it just returns zero and I'm not sure how to change it to make it work

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
leap_counter = 0
```

Outside of the while loop. Currently it's getting set to `0` each iteration